# php .htaccess url rewrite incorrect parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a strange problem using .htaccess RewriteEngine.

I have this simple rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.\*)/(.\*).php$ pages/test.php?lang1=$1&page1=$2 [L]
```

In pages/test.php I put this php code:

```
echo('lang: '.$_GET['lang1'].'< br />');    
echo('page: '.$_GET['page1'].'< br />');    
echo('querystring: '.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
```

So, when calling http://test.local/en-US/something.php, I would expect something like:

```
lang: en-US    
page: something    
querystring: lang1=en-US&page1=something
```

Instead, this is the weird output I get from the page:

```
lang: pages    
page: test    
querystring: lang1=pages&page1=test
```

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get that result because you created a loop, try using these lines :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pages/test\.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)\.php$ /pages/test.php?lang1=$1&page1=$2 [L]
```

Comment: It works like a charm, thank you! I don't really understand why it went through a loop, though...

Comment: you redirect `^(.*)/(.*)\.php$` , `pages/test.php` matches the pattern too. anyway, glad it is now working :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the QSA flag:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*).php$ pages/test.php?lang1=$1&page1=$2 [QSA,L]
```

When the replacement URI contains a query string, the default behavior of RewriteRule is to discard the existing query string, and replace it with the newly generated one. Using the [QSA] flag causes the query strings to be combined.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html

Comment: Thank you, I tried the QSA flag but that was the result: lang1=pages&page1=test&lang1=en-US&page1=dfsdfasdf. I guess it's because of the loop problem above...

Comment: I reproduced your problem here, and it gave the right result. The L flag normally ends any further processing. If the other answer worked out, it's fine too :)